# Passing type parameter to generic type with no constraints is throwing a constraint exception

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

Consider the following code:

```
IEnumerable<Type> oneParameterTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(object))
                                      .GetTypes()
                                      .Where(t => t.IsGenericType)
                                      .Where(t => t.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
                                      .Where(t => t.GetGenericArguments().Single().GetGenericParameterConstraints().Length == 0);
```

`oneParameterTypes` should hold all the generic types in the `System.dll` assembly, that can be passed a single generic type parameter and apply no constraint to it.

Now, let's pass in a type parameter:

```
IEnumerable<Type> intParameterTypes = oneParameterTypes.Select(t => t.MakeGenericType(typeof(int)))
                                                       .ToList();
```

This should work, right? I mean, all the types in `oneParameterTypes` should have no type constraints, so `System.Int32` should be a valid type.

Yet, the line throws the following exception:

> GenericArguments[0], 'System.Int32', on 'System.RuntimeType+ListBuilder`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'.

What is this `ListBuilder'1` type and why is it in `oneParameterTypes` if it has a type constraint? Why is my `Where` filter not working?

Comment: I think it's because the class has constraints on the generic type for `class`, but not for a specific class. (rather than `struct`) For example, if you run your code on an empty `public class Test<T> where T : class { }`, it will fail in the exact same way. Off the top of my head, I'm not sure how exactly you check for that, or why it necessarily doesn't get covered in your `Where` clauses.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair That's disappointing. `where T : class` is a type constraint, yet it is not included in `type.GetGenericParameterConstraints()`. Is this intended or is it a bug?

Comment: I don't think so. See [@Szabolcs' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33530532/1269654). It's just additional attributes you have to look for. I believe `GetGenericParameterConstraints` only checks for _type inheritance_ constraints, not `class/struct` or covariance/contravariance constraints. EDIT: Perhaps those are considered "attributes" rather than constraints. Regardless, I do agree that the naming is a bit ambiguous or confusing, even if it is technically correct (assuming it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Chris is correct.

Try it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Type> oneParameterTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (object))
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsGenericType)
    .Where(t => t.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
    .Where(t => t.GetGenericArguments().Single().GetGenericParameterConstraints().Length == 0 &&
                !genericArgument.GenericParameterAttributes.HasFlag(GenericParameterAttributes.ReferenceTypeConstraint);
    });
```

Comment: I think this will probably work, though you may want to check with `!= GenericParameterAttributes.ReferenceTypeConstraint` instead (as there are a few others which you may want to include, like `in` and `out`)

Comment: Correct. My initial try returned 125 items, the one with the `!= GenericParameterAttributes.ReferenceTypeConstraint` returns 141.

Comment: Also, I'm still incorrect. I didn't notice that `GenericParameterAttributes` is a bitwise flags enum, which in retrospect makes sense. So you shouldn't check for `!= GenericParameterAttributes.ReferenceTypeConstraint` either, but instead do a bitwise flags check to see if it contains that flag.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation isn't really clear about what `Type.GetGenericParameterConstraints` actually looks for:

> Use the IsClass property to determine whether a constraint is the base class constraint; if the property returns false, the constraint is an interface constraint. **If a type parameter has no class constraint and no interface constraints, an empty array is returned.**

You can implicitly understand that it will only check for a *base class or interface constraint*. To get the complete picture around which constraints exist, you'll need to have additional checks on `GenericParameterAttributes`. You can either use `HasFlag` or a bitwise mask:

```
IEnumerable<Type> oneParameterTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(object))
              .GetTypes()
              .Where(t => t.IsGenericType)
              .Where(t => t.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
              .Where(t => t.GetGenericArguments().Single().GetGenericParameterConstraints().Length == 0 && !t.GenericParameterAttributes.HasFlag(GenericParameterAttributes.ReferenceTypeConstraint);
```

Comment: Correct, except one small nitpicking, it's called HasFlag, not HasFlags.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thx, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

typeof() or .GetType() method does not return the actual class, instead they will return the Type Object representation, which will help us in using the type name as a string.

Instead, you can use reflection classes and find the class of that type and use that as a parameter